# Visual Studio 2015: None of the Web Essentials features work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I am unable to use any of the features of Web Essentials. Currently when I right click a folder, .less, .css or any relevant file for that matter, this is what I get. (Picture below)

I have tried repairing Visual Studio, and I have uninstalled and installed Web Essentials, but I still only get this.

Have anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks

[image: Web Essentials Menu]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYuX0.png):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important! Bundling, minification and compilation of LESS, Sass and CoffeeScript is not longer part of Web Essentials 2015.

Install the new extensions Bundler & Minifier and Web Compiler instead. Also, see this list of other web development extensions that might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the components of Web Essentials were incorporated in to Visual Studio 2015. There is a really good video on Microsoft's Channel 9 featuring Web Essentials Developer Mads Kristensen who explains what has moved from Web Essentials in to the Visual Studio 2015 product as well as the future of Web Essentials.

[Modern Web Development Tools in Visual Studio 2015 with Mads Kristensen](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Modern-Web-Development-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2015-with-Mads-Kristensen)

Hopefully that answers your questions about Web Essentials